# Problema con identificador en el query

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy realizando una consulta donde clasifico una colummna por tipo y dependiendo de esto colocarle si es válido o no se toma en cuenta, este es el query que tengo:

```
select 
   nombre as nombre,
   tipo_banco as tipo,
   decode(tipo_banco,'PRIVADO',1,0) as valido,
   case when valido = 1 then 'Válido' else 'No tomar en cuenta' end as valido2
from banco2
```

Lo que quería hacer era tomar ese alias "valido" para saber cuales tienen 1 pero no funciona como quería y me lanza el siguiente error:

> ORA-00904: "VALIDO": identificador no válido
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error en la línea: 236, columna: 14

La línea 236 es donde está el `case when valido=1` ...

Hay alguna manera de hacer esto? no sé si me di a explicar bien lo que necesito hacer, Gracias de antemano

Comment: https://logic.edchen.org/how-to-resolve-ora-00904-invalid-identifier/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si. La mayoria de las bases de datos no aceptan que pongas el nombre de un campo que acabas de generar en el mismo query...

Lo que tenes que hacer, es repetir la funcion cada vez que lo necesites.

```
select 
   nombre as nombre,
   tipo_banco as tipo,
   decode(tipo_banco,'PRIVADO',1,0) as valido,
   case when decode(tipo_banco,'PRIVADO',1,0) = 1 
        then 'Válido' 
        else 'No tomar en cuenta' 
    end as valido2
from banco2
```

Comment: ok entonces tendría que repetir siempre la sentencia para que pueda funcionar, así como me dices funciona perfecto

Comment: O hacer un select que tenga como ingreso este select. de esa otra forma, los nombres de campo ya existen. Tene en cuenta que las DB tienen un orden para hacer las cosas, y lo ultimo que hacen es el AS del select. por lo tanto, si pones ese nombre en otro campo, lo va a buscar a la tabla y no sabe a cual te referis.

Comment: vale entonces me serviría hacer un with que tenga ese select para luego no estar repitiendo esa sentencia siempre que la necesite, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: exactamente @Jesús!!! esa es una excelente solucion

Answer (score 3):

La sintaxis del `CASE` en Oracle es algo distinta, sutil, pero distinta de lo que tienes, debería ser

```
select 
   nombre as nombre,
   tipo_banco as tipo,
   decode(tipo_banco,'PRIVADO',1,0) as valido,
   case valido when 1 then 'Válido' else 'No tomar en cuenta' end as valido2
from banco2
```

Comment: vale no sabía que la sintaxis también se podía colocar de esta manera, aunque igualmente si lo coloco como me dices me sigue dando el error :S

Comment: Esto en que version de oracle funciona?

Comment: Al menos en la 10.2 ([documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm))

Comment: no pregunto por el case, si no por usar el nombre de un campo que acabas de crear en el mismo query. Eso no funciona.